# Google sign-In "Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience"

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate Google Sign-In to my Node.js website following the guide at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth. I'm able to log in and authenticate with my back end server on localhost but not on my Heroku environment. It gives the error `"Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience"`. Here is the backend authentication code.

```
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const googleClient = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
let token = req.body.token;
let user = {};

async function verify() {
    const ticket = await googleClient.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: CLIENT_ID
    });
    const payload = ticket.getPayload();
    user.name = payload.name;
    user.email = payload.email;
    user.picture = payload.picture;
    user.id = payload.sub;
}
verify()
    .then(() => {
        res.cookie('session-token', token);
        res.send('success');
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

CLIENT_ID has been added to Heroku's config vars. Both local host and my heroku url have been added to my google credentials page. [image] What would cause the authentication to work on localhost but not on Heroku?

Comment: Remove local host url and check

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: Any solution found ?